# How to set size of JTextField in pixels

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtextfield, preferredsize

Hey I was just wondering if there is a way to set JTextField width for example 50% of the screen size. I know how to get the dimensions of screen just JTextField sets it to number of characters not pixels

textfield = new JTextField("Way hello there", 20);

is there a way to do this ?

Comment: forgot about set coordinates in pixels, have to use proper LayoutManger, there are a two-tree LayoutManagers that can do that by default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the size of `JTextField` in pixels leads you down the path of using absolute positioning which is generally not advisable. From [Doing Without a Layout Manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html)

> Although it is possible to do without a layout manager, you should use a layout manager if at all possible. Layout managers also can be reused easily by other containers, as well as other programs.

Have a look at the functionality offered by existing [layout managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) and [avoid using the *setXXXSize()* component methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi). For example, `GridLayout` ( or even `GridBagLayout`) can be used to size a `JTextField` width to 50% of a frame client area.

Answer (score -1):

You may use setSize() method to set the size of JTextField component.

```
public void setSize(int width,
                    int height)
```

Resizes this component so that it has width width and height height.
Parameters:
**width** - the new width of this component in pixels
**height** - the new height of this component in pixels

Javadoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setSize(int, int)

**Edit:**
Any component added to the GridLayout will be resized to the same size as the largest component added. If you want a component to remain at its preferred size, then wrap that component in a JPanel and then the panel will be resized:

Also use `setPreferredSize` instead of `setSize`.

Comment: hmm tried this it doesn't seem to change the size. It is still the width of the text inside the text field.

Comment: Never, ever, use set[Preferred|Minimum|Maximum]Size. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi